# C++11 with Xcode

Tags: c++11, auto

I am trying to compile following code (from header file):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    auto &GetString() const { return m_str1; }
private:
    std::wstring m_str1;
};
```

On the Mac with Xcode it gives following:

```
'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are C++14 extension.
```

As far as I know `auto` is C++11 feature and shouldn't need anything from C++14.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is exactly what the error says.

C++11 :

```
auto &GetString() const -> std::wstring& { return m_str1; }
```

C++14 :

```
auto &GetString() const  { return m_str1; }
```

There are more new uses for `auto` since C++11. E.g.

C++20:

```
int function(auto data)
```